# In the real world, is probability discrete or continuous?

Tags: probability

I am not quite sure whether this belongs on math SE. Anyway, my question is this. In math, probability can theoretically be any real number between 0 and 1 inclusive. But what about in the real world? I don't think an event in the real world can have, say, pi percent probability. So, in the real world, is probability discrete, or continuous?

Comment: I don’t think the ratio of a circle’s circumference to its diameter is pi in the real world either... no measurement is *perfect*.

Comment: Probability does not reside in the real world, only in our models of it, and reflects our state of knowledge in addition to external facts. An event cannot have probability *π* for the simple reason that *π>1*, but one can come up with a quantum system our model of which will assign probability *1/π* to some outcome.

Comment: @Conifold I did not mean pi, I meant pi percent, in other words, pi/100.

Comment: *π/100* is just as good as *1/π* or *1/2*.

Comment: It's worth noting that discrete and continuous are not the only possibilities. That being said, any probability measure can be expressed as a linear combination of a discrete measure, a singular continuous measure, and an absolutely continuous measure.

Comment: ∀x∀n∀p {p=x/n∧x≤n∧(x,n)∈ℝ ⇒p∈ℝ}

Answer (score 1):

Probability is calculated as the ratio of the number of favorable outcomes out of the number of mutually exclusive possible outcomes (which I'll refer to as `x/n` here).

The answer to your question depends on whether the set of possible outcomes is countable and finite in the real world — which is not a settled issue.

**If the number of possible outcomes is countable and finite**, then a subset would be as well. Both `x` and `n` would be integers and the ratio `x/n` would therefore be rational. The set of rational numbers is discrete and not continuous, so then probabilities would necessarily be discrete too.

However, **if the set of possible outcomes is infinite, even if it is countable**, you can get irrational probabilities. For example, the density of all [square-free integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) (that is, the probability of choosing such an integer out of the infinite number of natural numbers) is `6 / (pi^2)`, an irrational number. You can research more about this on the Wikipedia entry on [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

And there's also a possibility that there are **some aspects of nature that are continuous**, which would also allow for continuous probabilities.